# Cordova: unable to add android platform

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I've just generated a new Ionic1 app using "sidemenu" template.
No plugin added, no extra dependencies.

I get the error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\node_modules\brace-expansion
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\node_modules\brace-expansion' -> 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\brace-expansion-7416809b'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\node_modules\brace-expansion' -> 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\brace-expansion-7416809b'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\node_modules\brace-expansion' -> 'C:\myApp\node_modules\.staging\brace-expansion-7416809b'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\\node_modules\\brace-expansion',
npm ERR!      dest: 'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\brace-expansion-7416809b' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\\node_modules\\brace-expansion\' -> \'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\brace-expansion-7416809b\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\cordova-android-dbc95b4b\\node_modules\\brace-expansion',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\nodejs\\fuckit\\node_modules\\.staging\\brace-expansion-7416809b',
npm ERR!   parent: 'fuckit' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I'm on a powershell running as admin.

```
node 8.9.4
npm 5.1.0
cordova 8.0.0
ionic 3.19.1
```

**SOLVED(?):** as the other 4-5 times I faced this problem, I solved but I do not know how. I simply tried to reinstall node (v8 and v9), npm (different versions), cordova (different versions), nvm. After ~15 hours completely wasted on this, I solved at the 4th complete refresh of the node/npm environment. NPM is simply a cruel nightmare.

---

**EDIT:** I suspect I solved because I changed the npm directory from

```
%APPDATA%/npm
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

using the command

```
npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Comment: try running 'npm cache clean -f' or 'npm cache verify'. Also ensure that node_modules folder is not read only

Comment: Use cmd as system Administrator

Comment: Just read the log → Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: I already tried `npm cache clean --force` and as I said I running already the powershell as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly there are several tickets on the [npm's GitHub issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues) page adressing your problem. Futhermore one of my teammates ran into exact the same issue as well today… So just have a look at their issues page or try one of the proposed solutions:

- Update your `npm` to a newer version
- Close your `IDE` e.g. `VSCode` or `Visual Studio` and `npm install` again
- Kill all running node instances from your task manager and `npm install` again
- …

Comment: obiouvsly I tried..nothing works. NPM is a real nightmare.

Comment: Have you looked at the other issues as well?

Comment: I periodically have this problem, and waste 1-2 days on it. I searched for days so long. It looks the root cause is not indentified yet from the npm team....it's ridiculous, the issue comes from 2014.